# htaccess instead of a php/mysql login solution

Tags: php, apache

Is is using .htaccess password protection  on a website more secure than using php and mysql?

Is it possible to create a custom page that uses the .htaccess mechanism instead of the regular htacces dialogue box.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP authentication through Apache's .htaccess provides a login mask where the browser asks the user for a username and a password.
But then the data inserted by the user is still sent to a server-side program to verify that data.

Which means that interface passes data through HTTP to PHP (for example), which will need a database (MySQL, for example) to store the users data.

.htaccess files may store some users data, but it's not that scalable so it's not recommended. You can't add too many users to Apache's configs.

Answer (score 0):

So to start to answer this I would say you need to do some searching yourself.  Here is a good page to get started http://www.image-maps.com/tools/apache-htaccess-password-generator/  they discuss htaccess and htpassword encryption options such as:Crypt, MD5, SHA1.  This question is difficult to answer because you as which is "more secure".  The question I have is what do you mean.  Is one method have better encryption or are you asking is the handling of the hashed password data done better in one versus the other?  MySQL info is here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html It allows for SHA1 160-bit encryption but these can be broken given the right situation.  I think the best question to ask your self is what is it you are trying to achieve and ask that on the forum.